# How to efficently multiply a circulant matrix A $\in \{-1,+1\}^{d \times d}$ with a vector x $ \in \mathbb{R}^{d} $?

Tags: matrices

I know the way of multiplying using FFT which takes $O(dlgd)$. If you know something better please share. 
If you have some nontrivial method for general matrices (not circulant), then also please reply. Any suggestions related to this question will help.

Comment: It will be sufficent for me, if you can give a better way to multiply circulant matrix A$\in \{0,1\}^{d\times d}$ with vector x$\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$.